# Android: Dynamically Change TextView Background color

Tags: android, textview, background-color

I have following textview in my Activity. I want to change the background color of the textview dynamically.

My problem is I don't want to get the colors from Resouce file or other colors.RED method. I'm getting colors from webservie in websafe mode (i.e #FFF, #000 etc).

How can I pass these colors as background to TextView. Thanks in advance for your time.

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/colorCode"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:background="#FF0000" android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Below is snippet might help you where `txtChannelName` is an object of `TextView`

```
 txtChannelName.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

or

```
txtChannelName.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

Comment: Thanks but I was already aware of this method. I mentioned in my question too about this //colors from Resouce file or other colors.RED method// I wanna know whether I can pass #FFF as input to background color of a textview??.

Answer (score 8):

yow can set color from android or color in format rbg like this:

```
TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourId);
txtView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#AA3456"));
```

or:

```
txtView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
String color = "FF0000";   // For example your color is FF0000
TextView txt = new TextView(this);         
txt.setBackgroundColor(Integer.parseInt(color, 16)+0xFF000000);
```

OR

```
//This is the most preferrable
txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
```

Answer (score 2):

In your activity you do something like that:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.colorCode);
int myDynamicColor = Color.parseColor("#FFFF00"); // Here you can pass a string taken from the user or from wherever you want.
textView.setBackgroundColor(myDynamicColor);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is wot I'm talking about :)

Answer (score 1):

You can now change your background color programatically. 100% working for me. Try it.

```
 RelativeLayout relativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
 relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(yourContext, R.color.yourColor));
```

Thanks me later.

Answer (score 0):

XML file saved at res/values/colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <color name="opaque_red">#f00</color>
   <color name="translucent_red">#80ff0000</color>
</resources>
```

Then from your program access those color like following:

```
Resources res = getResources();
int color = res.getColor(R.color.opaque_red);
textView.setBackgroundColor(color);
```